# Unhandled Petrel exception after running unit tests

Tags: ocean, petrel

I have Petrel 2012 unit tests that ran successfully using nunit.  I added some new unit tests.  These tests use some custom domain objects which I register.  I also am using a different Petrel project for the tests.

When running Nunit, it runs my tests and they are successful, however, after nunit reports the results, nunit crashes :

> UNHANDLED EXCEPTION in Petrel 2012.1 64-bit (CL 345168, built Jul 27
>   2012): Likely Cause:       Likely singleton issue: Managed code
>   attempted executed after CLR shut down. Exception Type:
>   0xC0020001: The string binding is invalid. Exception Details: 
>   Exception occurred at offset 0xDD50 in module KERNEL32.dll Exception
>   Handler:  Petrel unhandled exception filter (native init) Exception
>   Thread:   Unnamed thread (id 3908) Report Number:      0 Report ID:
>   {8c53496a-ff6e-46e0-b536-a85868246cef} Native stack trace:
>   KERNEL32.dll+0xDD50  PulseEvent+0x60    clr.dll+0x45A454
>   clr.dll+0x5B46D3    clr.dll+0x189C1A    Core.Subjects.dll+0xF7138 
>   BaseAllSubjectsItr::init+0x58    Core.Subjects.dll+0xF7351 
>   BaseAllSubjectsItr::BaseAllSubjectsItr+0x31
>   Core.Subjects.dll+0x4E919 
>   NotificationManagerImpl::notifyBeforeRemove+0x59
>   Core.Subjects.dll+0xE034E  FolderSubject::removeKidAt+0x9E
>   Core.Subjects.dll+0xDFED1  FolderSubject::removeAllKids+0x31
>   Core.Subjects.dll+0xCA307  ParentSubject::cleanup+0x17
>   Foundation.Primitives.BaseClasses.dll+0xB434 
>   MemorySaver::MemorySaver+0x224
>   Foundation.Primitives.BaseClasses.dll+0x2777C  Shared::unref+0x1C
>   Foundation.Primitives.BaseClasses.dll+0x18EE  Shared::unref+0xE
>   Sim.Domain.Analysis.dll+0x1F5CCE 
>   FunctionPlotCmd::~FunctionPlotCmd+0x3E
>   Sim.Domain.Analysis.dll+0x783F7
>   Foundation.Primitives.BaseClasses.dll+0xB463 
>   MemorySaver::MemorySaver+0x253
>   Foundation.Primitives.BaseClasses.dll+0x2777C  Shared::unref+0x1C
>   Foundation.Primitives.BaseClasses.dll+0x18EE  Shared::unref+0xE
>   Core.Subjects.dll+0xE169  UpdateHint::operator=+0x2C9
>   Core.Subjects.dll+0x12CDC4    Core.Subjects.dll+0x4979F 
>   Slb::Petrel::Configuration::ServiceBase::create+0x42F
>   Core.Subjects.dll+0x499E9 
>   Slb::Petrel::Configuration::ServiceBase::create+0x679
>   ntdll.dll+0x149BF  RtlGetCurrentDirectory_U+0x1FF
>   KERNEL32.dll+0x1A35C  ExitProcess+0x2C    mscoreei.dll+0x18552
>   mscoreei.dll+0x183E4    clr.dll+0x238787    clr.dll+0x23980C
>   clr.dll+0x171966    clr.dll+0x16F567    clr.dll+0x133835 
>   CorExeMain+0x15    mscoreei.dll+0x3309  CorExeMain+0x49
>   mscoree.dll+0x5B21  CorExeMain+0x69    KERNEL32.dll+0x196AC 
>   BaseProcessStart+0x2C Managed stack trace: Failed to collect managed
>   stack trace.
>
> Proceeding to invoke Windows Error Reporting...

I also tried to use the Petrel project that I was using before this error but now I get the same exception.  Any ideas?

Comment: Is your plugin fully managed? Do you have any unmanaged bits in your plugin code?

Comment: Yes its fully managed. I do use a third party library but I believe it is fully managed as well.

Comment: The problem has fixed itself for the moment. The power went out and caused a reboot of the build server. When the server came back up, the problem disappeared.

Comment: @Web it is good if you put your comment as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reboot of the build server fixed the problem.